# Adding image to the particular li

Tags: jquery

I have a list of li tags with an image. When a user clicks a particular link i want to change the image. When a user clicks a new li tag then the last li tag should reset. I done everything except to set a new image for the particular li tag. And the major problem is i'm not passing any arguments to the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sized ul li a").click(function(){
    $('.sized ul li a img').each(function(){$(this).remove(); }); // Removing all images
    $('.sized ul li a ').each(function(){$(this).append('<img src="1.png" />'); });// Reset the images
});
```

Comment: where the new image names come from ?

Comment: Tags in titles and greetings in posts not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why it is a problem to not pass any arguments.

Instead of removing and adding a new image for all links, just change the one that was clicked before. You can change the image by just changing its `src` attribute with [**`.attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(function() {
    var $prev;
    $(".sized ul li a").click(function(){
        if($prev) {
            $prev.find('img').attr('src', '1.png');
        }
        $prev = $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'new-url-here').end();
    });
});
```